# how can i compare a start time with the system clock using ctime/chrono libaray

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm running into a error trying to compile the program with conversion from double to int. What I want is to be able to display out the difference not just in seconds but in hours/minutes/seconds but I can't think of how to make the difftime work. If there is a better option like using chrono, I would appreciate the help.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::tm now{},; 
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point cc;

    std::cout << "enter\nyear month day\n";

    std::cin >> now.tm_year >> now.tm_mon >> now.tm_mday;

    now.tm_year -= 1900;
    now.tm_mon -= 1;


    std::time_t n = std::mktime(&now);
    cc = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(n);
    n = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(cc);

    std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&n), "%FT%T") << "\n";
    std::time_t system_time = time(nullptr);
    std::cout << asctime(localtime(&system_time));

    double fc = difftime(system_time, mktime(&now));
    std::cout << "time diff "<< fc << endl;

}
```

Comment: Only compiler issue I see here is `endl` should be `std::endl`

Comment: Please, remove `visual-c++` tag

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout the date lib from howard hinnant.
https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date
The tz lib in it Can do your local time diff calculation in without converting it to utc. (normally you should always convert to utc before calculation, because of the daylight saving time) It also contains format functions to stream it in hour min sec format.

Comment: yeah I'm looking over the link now but I still would like to know how I could convert say fc back into years/months/day/hour/min/sec. If so I also add those in so it can be displayed back out so its easier to read. would I have to use % and just break down fc for each day/month/year?

Comment: @MarcusWilliams: Glad to help if I can.  But I'm not sure I completely understand your question.  So far I've got:  You want the user to input the local date, assume the time is the first instant of that date.  And then compute the time elapsed since that user input?  Specifically counting in Unix Time, which will count physical time (no effect of daylight saving), but neglect leap seconds from that physical time.  But then converting `fc` back into a time point is problematic.  `fc` is a duration.  Do you mean add `fc` back to the user-input epoch to obtain a time point?

Answer (score 0):

The better way of doing it is using a *steady_clock* instead of *system_clock*.
I don't know what your task is but you may use another class such as Stopwatch to generate elapsed time.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
class StopWatch {
private:
chrono::time_point<chrono::steady_clock> start;
public:
void reset() { start = chrono::steady_clock::now(); }
StopWatch() { reset(); }
double elapsedSeconds() {
chrono::duration<double> d = chrono::steady_clock::now() - start;
return chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(d).count() / 1000000.;
}};
```

After that, you can simply use Stopwatch:

```
int main(void){
Stopwatch s;
cout<<s.elapsedSeconds();
}
```

Comment: I need the user to input a date and time then I want to compare it to the system clock and see what time I have left and I want it displayed back again but not in seconds like the input sat 11 2019 06:34:30 but it shows the difference if that makes sense. just very lost when it comes down to using chrono and ctime